# Ng-Repeat Limit but Include all of array when using filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table as shown below:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="td-img" ng-repeat="value in values | limitTo: 5 | filter: valueFilter" align="center"><img width="150" height="200" src="{{value.title}}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I limit it to 5 cause I only want it show 5 at a time but I also have a filter for my ng-repeat which is this function which is currently blank:

```
$scope.valueFilter = function(element)
{
    return true;
}
```

However, when I try and filter the table only 5 elements appear at a time because of the limit. Is there a way to limit the items to show to 5 but also include all values in the array for filtering?

**Solution found, suggested by [Guramidev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2907653/guramidev):**

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="td-img" ng-repeat="value in values | filter: valueFilter | limitTo: 5" align="center"><img width="150" height="200" src="{{value.title}}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

By switching the filter infront of the limit, this allows it to limit to 5 as well as get all the elements in the array.

Comment: did you try to apply filter first and than limit?

Comment: @guramidev Just did and worked like a charm!

Comment: @guramidev Is it possible to randomise the result of the filter even it is limited to 5?

Comment: you will have to create your own filter for that

Comment: @guramidev How do you mean?